# Enabling managed identity for AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to enable Managed Identity on my AKS, to do that I run the command below;

```
az aks update -g myRg -n myAKS --enable-managed-identity
```

And it successfully finished. So after this point I don't see any new Managed Identity in "Managed Identity" resource list. Or no new entry in AKS' IAM.

How can I find that which Managed Identity I enabled for my AKS cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my environment Enabled Managed Identity on my AKS like below:

```yaml
az aks update -g myRg -n myAKS --enable-managed-identity
```

[image]

[image]

> **How can I find that which Managed Identity I enabled for my AKS cluster?**

To find managed identity, Go to Enterprise Applications -> All applications.

[image]

Search your managed identity object id you can find your Aks managed identity like below:

[image]

Additionally, you can add filter on application type like below:

[image]